# How can I login programmatically into Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore5.2

How can I login programmatically into Sitecore?
For example if you would like to connect a small part of the Sitecore API to a desktop application, you would need to login into sitecore first to access the databases etc.

Can this be done?

Comment: As a heads-up, you need to be very careful if you are writing data using the Sitecore API directly to a database without informing any running website instances that their caches are now stale.  Sitecore caches quite aggressively, and so you will almost invariably encounter caching problems if you're doing anything moderately complex.  This can be avoided using 6.3 I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mark said, you will need to create a web service that your desktop app will talk to. If you need to deal with permissions in that service you have two options.

1. Use a SecurityDisabler to make your webservice run in the context of an Admin user.

   ```cs
   using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
   {
       // do stuff here
   }
   ```
2. For more specific control you can use a UserSwitcher.

   From the [Security API Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20API%20Cookbook.aspx) page 34

   ```cs
   string domainUser = @"domain\user"; 

   if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(domainUser)) 
   { 
       Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = 
       Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(domainUser,false); 

       using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(user)) 
       { 
           //TODO: code to invoke as user 
       } 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Not really. What you can do, however, is write a supporting web service for your desktop application, and have that run in a Sitecore context.

Comment: Ok, but even with a web service, how do I do it ? I also need to login to access Sitecore items. What am I missing here ?

Comment: No, you can do it without a web service. I'll try to dig out the code. You don't really 'login' when you use Sitecore's API. With the API, you're coming in with full access.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to accomplish your goal:

1. Create a desktop application and
   reference the same version of the
   Sitecore binaries that your web app
   uses.
2. Configure your desktop application
   to point to the same Sitecore DBs as
   your web site.
3. Use the security disabler and then
   set the context as follows:
   Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("website");

Sitecore may tell you that what you are trying to do will not work.  But trust me, this works and I've used this method in a project before.

Additional details:
Sitecore uses the Master, Core and Web DBs as it's data store.  My suggested method uses Sitecore APIs to write directly to the DBs.  When using this method, you'll need to be aware of the cache implications.

cheers!

Comment: I worked on the same project as Anand where we did this. In our solution, we also had lots of the Sitecore .config and .xml files in there, so don't forget them.

Comment: What are the licensing implications of this approach?