# How do I remote login to Sitecore using Ajax

Tags: sitecore

Is there any way to login standard Sitecore 6.4 in JavaScript without having to create custom server-side code [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234832/how-can-i-login-programatically-into-sitecore)? I am trying to login in order to open Sitecore application using JavaScript but normal Sitecore login requires postback and default WebService does not log me in either. 
I even tried to iFrame standard login screen but it has:

```
if (window.top.frames.length > 0) {
  window.top.location = window.location;
}
```

in the load that hijacks my html.

Is there any way to post login into clean Sitecore on client-side?

Comment: Can you provide more info, please? What sitecore application are you trying to open and why?

Comment: I am trying to open any application really but let's say Content Editor.

Comment: The idea is to be able to have simple .html file on PC desktop and mobile to update single item in Sitecore. It would be useful for other simple things as well such as Workflow approvals. I can easily do that except there is no any API in default Sitecore to login using Form Post or WebService.