# NullReferenceException when calling Sitecore Database.Templates[] inside WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, sitecore

I'm new to Sitecore development, so my apologies if this question is basic.  I've created both an agent (scheduled task) and a WCF service and have them both added to my SiteCore project.  The agent calls the same code the WCF service code calls.

The issue I am having is that when I call `Database.Template[ID template]` passing in the ID container of the corresponding template for an item I want to process, it works inside the agent task, but not inside the WCF service.

Any call to `Database.Template[ID id]` inside the WCF service is giving me a `NullReferenceException`, however the exact same call inside the agent gathers up the template properly.

Is this due to some structural reason dependent on the calling application being a webpage instead of a webservice?

Edit #1:  I have svc as an allowed extension, and I have tried both

```
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master")
```

and

```
var siteContext = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite("websiteMaster");
siteContext.Database.Template[];
```

both which return `NullReferenceException`.

I also can successfully obtain an Item, using `GetItem`, however when I try to access the Template property of that item, I get a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have no Sitecore Context from your WCF service and so `Sitecore.Context.Database` is null.

You can either add `svc` to the list of allowed extensions or get the data via `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master")`

- [Attach WCF services to Sitecore context](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/03/attach-wcf-services-to-sitecore-context.html)
- [Access Sitecore data with WCF](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/access-sitecore-data-with-wcf/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I actually have private static Sitecore.Data.Database DB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master"); defined as part of my service implementation and still get this error.  Also, svc was added in the web.config as an allowed extension.

Comment: I agree with jammykam point on this one. If you dont have any DB reference mentioned, then you will get null at his point where you are calling GetDatabase!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few parts to this question

- Programmatically Accessing Items using Sitecore Database
- Sitecore Security
- WCF & Sitecore HTTPContext

Programmatically Accessing Items using Sitecore Database

- Creating a WCF service to use with reading/editing Sitecore items would require accessing the Sitecore database, see [Programmatically Login into Sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234832/how-can-i-login-programatically-into-sitecore)
- (As already mentioned), using `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(Database)` explicitly will get you the database, however that brings up issue number 2.
- To take advantage of built in Sitecore functionality, it's more flexible to use the `Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase` or `Sitecore.Context.Database` methods to return the proper database based on the context in which the request is made; CD, CM server, etc.

Security

- While the security disabler will work to remove all security issues with accessing the Sitecore Database it's not recommended. 
  [Alex Soft and Sitecore Security](http://sitecore.alexiasoft.nl/2005/12/24/sitecore-security-i-do-it-my-way/)

  ```cs
  using (new SC.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(User.FromName(ServiceAccountName, true)))
  {
      // code here
  }
  ```

more properly aligns with [Sitecore's Security API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf), provides a security trail of transactions and enables versioning of changed items completed by the services. Such information will help with bug tracking and auditing.

WCF and the Sitecore HTTPContext:

- You may run into issues with using WCF and objects that use the  Sitecore HTTPContext.
- If you want to use `Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase` or `Sitecore.Context.Database` in your WCF service, you'll likely get an null exceptions from the Database, especially if running the service on a CD instance.
- The one liner golden egg to overcoming this limitation is to set the Active site using `Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite(SiteName)`, at some point in the service, (usually the constructor).
- The SiteName is name of the list of site's available in the Sitecore/Sites section of the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an ideal solution, but I converted this nearly line for line from a WCF service to an ASMX based service and everything works well.  The only issue I had, was when calling the service I got an Access permission issue.

I wrapped the ASMX service function contents inside a block of this type:

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler()) { }
```

And everything magically started working.  I'm starting to wonder if this isn't a bug with the Sitecore framework that I encountered.  If anyone knows how to submit a formal report, please let me know.

Comment: This actually makes sense since an anonymous user would generally not have direct access to templates. Did you try adding the security disabler in the WCF code? Raise a ticket with [Sitecore Support](https://support.sitecore.net) if you think it is a bug.

Comment: Whats the difference b/w ASMX Vs. WCF when you are calling Sitecore Database?

Answer (score 0):

also worth checking Website\App_Config\Include\SwitchMasterToWeb.config and renaming/removing if required as it makes the master database appear as web otherwise.  As its a patch config it can be easily missed when troubleshooting.